# Angular using built-in services

Tags: angular2-services

Are there built-in services defined in Angular2 like $location in AngularJS? I tried Angular documentation but found only defining custom services in Angular2

Answer (score 0):

Import the ActivatedRoute, (and the rest of the Router stuff too, if you want)

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';
```

making sure it's injected into the constructor,

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { ... }
```

and on ngOnInit you can use this.route to inspect the URL. For instance, all the segments are in an array, which you can string together like this:

```
var parts: string;
this.route.url.forEach((segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
    parts = segments.join("/"));
});
```

to give you something like "mars/moons/phobos".